# Как в Android Studio исправить ошибку Gradle project sync failed?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

Android Studio версии 3.5.
Создал новый проект. По-началу выполняются все шаги быстро. После того, как все шаги выполнены (напротив них стоят зелёные галочки), загружается Gradle. Он долго загружается и потом выдаёт ошибку "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e. g. editing, debugging) will not work properly."
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Открыл лог. Вижу это. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотреть в логе что хочет, сделать это. Обновить загново.

Comment: Прикрепил свой лог

Comment: Написано, что не может скачать AGP 3.4.0. У вас есть подключение к интернет, оффлайн-режим грэдла не включен? И наверно лучше сразу сменить версию AGP на актуальную 3.5.0 (это в `build.gradle(project)`)

Comment: Нажмите `Help -> Check for Updates...` и соглашайтесь принять все изменения.